# Существуют ли промежуточные проверки в Play Market и AppStore?

Tags: android, ios, google-play, appstore

Всем привет!
Подскажет ли кто, существую ли дополнительные проверки приложений в магазинах Эпла/Гугла, в любое другое время, кроме непосредсвенно публикации самого приложеня или обновления? Вообще бывали ли случаи выявления нарушений и т.д. во время когда не публиковалось приложение/обновление? Спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

Да, конечно есть. Более того, вероятность публикации с 1-го раза стремится сейчас вообще к "нулю". Правил становится все больше и больше. С момента нажатия клавиши "Опубликовать" в личном кабинете разработчика маркет обычно берет до 2-х суток на проверку приложения. Отразить могут по совершенно разным причинам, например мое последнее приложение было отражено по следующей причине:

> Publishing status: Rejected
> Your app has been rejected and wasn't published due to a policy violation. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play.

> Reasons of violation
> Issue: Violation of Metadata policy
> We don't allow apps with misleading, improperly formatted, non-descriptive, irrelevant, excessive, or inappropriate metadata, including but not limited to the app's description, developer name, title, icon, screenshots, and promotional images. Developers must provide a clear and well-written description and avoid using repetitive or unrelated keywords or references. We also don't allow unattributed or anonymous user testimonials in the app's description.

Потратил в итоге на поиски причины примерно неделю, пока не выяснил, что в описании приложения одно из прилагательных было написано в превосходной степени:

*Completely safe*

Этого, по мнению маркета было достаточным для признания в нарушении политики :)

Comment: Понял, к чему нужно быть готовым, спасибо большое)